# Simple question about C++ constant syntax

Tags: c++, function, constants

Here is some code copied from Thinking in C++ Vol1 Chapter 10.

```
   #include <iostream>
   using namespace std;

   int x = 100;

   class WithStatic {
        static int x;
        static int y;
        public:
             void print() const {
             cout << "WithStatic::x = " << x << endl;
             cout << "WithStatic::y = " << y << endl;
           }
  };
```

what's the meaning of const for the function print()? Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98705/what-are-the-semantics-of-a-const-member-function and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49035/what-does-the-const-operator-mean-when-used-with-a-method-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've heard this described previously as “a method that does not logically change the object”. It means that by calling this method the caller can expect the object’s state to remain the same after the method returns. Effectively, the `this` pointer becomes a constant pointer to a constant instance of that class, so member variables cannot be altered. The exception to this rule is if member variables are declared with `mutable`. If a class has `mutable` member variables, these can be modified by both non-const and const methods. Also, non-const methods cannot be called from within a const method.

Some people use `mutable` member variables to cache results of timely computations. In theory, the state of the object does not change (i.e. the only effect is that subsequent calls are quicker, but they produce the same results given the same input).

Answer (score 2):

It means that it doesn't change any member variables of the class.

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html

Answer (score 1):

It's a guarantee that the function won't modify the object at all (i.e. it's a "read-only" function). EDIT: Apparently, the exception to that rule is if an object has `mutable` members; those can be changed by both const and non-const functions.

Also, I'm glad to see somebody else learning from TIC++. It's a great resource for beginners.

Comment: Not completely true, `mutable` members can be changed.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware of the `mutable` keyword. I'll change my answer.

Comment: `mutable` is rather a new development in C++.

Answer (score 1):

What it does is effectively make the `this` pointer be a const pointer to const instead of a const pointer to non-const. So, any time that you reference `this` in a const member function - either explicitly or implicitly - you're using a const pointer to const.

So, in the case of the class you have here, in any non-const function, the type of `this` is `WithStatic const *` while in the const functions, its type is `const WithStatic * const`.

Like with any pointer to const, you can't alter anything that it points to. So, you can't alter any of its member variables, and you can't call any of its non-const member functions.

Generally speaking, it's a good idea to make a member function be const if you can reasonably do so, because it guarantees that you're not going to alter the object's state, and you can call it with a const object.

It *is* possible for member variables to be altered if they're `mutable` or `volatile`, but those are more advanced topics that are probably better avoided until you're more familiar with the language. Certainly, you don't usually need to worry about them and shouldn't use them unless you need to. It's also possible to cast away the constness of the `this` pointer, at which point you could alter it, but IIRC, that's undefined behavior, and it's definitely generally considered a bad idea. So, there are instances where it's possible to alter an object's state within a const member function, but it's not normally possible and best avoided even when it is.

When you make a member function const, you're effectively promising that the object's state will not be changed by that function call (though there can obviously be side effects as evidenced by the fact that you can call functions like `printf()`).

Comment: No, `volatile` members can't be changed by const methods, only `mutable` ones. AFAIK, the only way to change non-mutable members is using `const_cast`.

Comment: Actually no, the type of this is: const WithStatic * (for non-const functions) and const WithStatic * const (for const functions). Pointer const goes after the asterisk.

Comment: Okay. Pointer syntax fixed. This is why I hate C++ pointer syntax. It gets so messy. As for volatile. No, you can't change it within a const function, but it *can* change out from under you. So, it does fit in with the things that go against the const-ness of a const function, but no, a const function cannot itself change a volatile variable.

Comment: Pointer syntax not fixed.  Try "in any non-const function, the type of `this` is `WithStatic * const`".

Comment: \*Sigh\*. Good catch. It was only half-fixed. Now it should be fully fixed. I guess that I was in too much of a hurry. It doesn't help that `const* T` is by far the most frequent way I use const with pointers. Pointer syntax is easy to mess up - especially if you're in a hurry and not actually compiling what you write. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If a member function is declared "const", it means that the function will not modify the object's state. This:

- Documents the fact that the function will not modify state (useful to other developers).
- Allows the compiler to make optimizations, knowing that the result of other "const" functions will not have changed as a result of calling that function (which allows function calls to be taken out of loops).
- Enables one to call the function when the object is passed by const reference, const pointer, etc.

For all the above reasons, one should, as a general rule of thumb, declare a function as "const" if it does not logically modify the state of  the object. If the logical state of the object changes, then don't use "const". As an aside, there are cases where the actual state changes but the logical state does not (e.g. caching), in which case one should still mark the function as "const", but one needs to use the "mutable" keyword with the caching variables in order to tell the compiler that modifying them actually doesn't change the logical state.

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively, it means that the method doesn't modify the object on which it is called.  But really, it means two things:

- The method may be called on an object or object pointer declared as `const`.
- Within the method, the `this` pointer becomes `const`.  Consequently, all members (except those declared `mutable`) are `const`, i.e. read-only, within the context of the method.  However, it may still modify:

  - data pointed to by members of the object it's called on
  - data accessed other than through the `this` pointer — including global data, data pointed to by the method's parameters, static members of the class, other objects of the class, even the same object (if it happens to have access to a non-const pointer to it or bypasses constancy using a `const_cast`).

Answer (score -1):

the const means print() is not allowed to modify state variables not marked with mutable.

Comment: iirc, it's an optional compile-time check, so while you *can*, it's a really bad idea to try to modify stuff.

Comment: @sreservoir, while it is only a compile-time check, you can (read: don't because you promised you wouldn't) modify non-const members, if you use a const_cast to remove the const from the this pointer. Members marked as mutable may be modified regardless of const-ness of the member function.

Comment: @sreservoir it's `mutable`, not `volatile`.

Comment: @Nathan Ernst: Are you sure that using `const_cast` to modify a `const` object is not undefined behaviour? It'll probably work on many systems but if it is undefined behaviour you can't rely on it working that way.

Comment: @dreamlax: It's undefined behavior if the object pointed to by `this` was created `const` (if it's a `const` global, it might even be in read-only memory).  If somebody created a `const` pointer to a writable object and passed it to a function that used `const_cast`, things work pretty much normally (unless you did something else bad like aliased a `restrict` pointer).

Comment: volatile has nothing to do with this. mutable is the keyword you're looking for.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Thanks for the insight. There is no way to know for sure whether the object was created non-const or const, is there? If not, then using `const_cast` to modify member variables in a `const` method is a tad dangerous.

Comment: @dreamlax: True.  The only legitimate purpose for `const_cast` is to pass a `const` pointer to a function whose contract is to not modify the object but failed to declare it as `const` (either because the function was written before `const` was standardized, or because the function conditionally modifies the parameter depending on other arguments).

Comment: (fixed after what, two years? it probably hardly matters at this point.)